# Sent Mail checking if it is delivered and open to recipient in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpmailer, swiftmailer, laravel-mail, email-delivery

I want help in **scaffolding code** with **Laravel** default Mail package to send an email to the recipient with an enhancement that checks the status either mail is **delivered** to recipient and then check that either recipient opened the mail or not and then change the status of that email in my **db_email_list**. I googled it that to add headers just like follow the example but could not get it how to get the status

```
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Confirm-Reading-To','recipient_mail');

$sendEmail->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Disposition-Notification-To','recipient_mail');

$sendEmail->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Return-Receipt-To','recipient_mail');
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that you will receive a response if you set these; most mail apps don't enable this because it's been exploited by spammers.

Answer (score 7):

**When the user has gotten the email**: Simply use this piece of code:

```
if (count(Mail::failures())) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

`true=delivered`, `false=not delivered`

**When user reads the email:** Hm sounds like you need to include a trick in your email in order to know if user has opened/read the email by simply adding for instance including an image on your email with a route defined in your end and passing user id as query param.

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/user-read-email?user_id=20" />
```

So whenever the user opens the email `img src` will fire a call to your url and simmply get the `user id` from the url,  and set the flag for that user in db.

Comment: Could this be a problem for spam filters somehow?

Comment: @Alberto content spam triggers are triggered from the mail content itself rather then source code, check SPF records of ur mail server to avoid ending up in spam